# AWS DMS to migrate databases to Amazon RDS Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently, we're using EC2 hosted Oracle and the DB size is around 200 GB. I want know if DMS is the best option for such type of Prod migration or what is the migration path to migrate from Ec2 Oracle to RDS-Oracle.

In Current Oracle DB there is around 100 GB of LOB objects, would there be any sort of issues in moving the DB to RDS along with LOB objects. The DB size is around 200 GB.

Could someone please suggest me the steps to migrate the data in the best way possible without lease downtime.

Comment: Did you check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen those options but if we go with any of options listed in the above post it require a huge downtime window.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Database Migration Service is intended to help with this type of migration.  It is documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html.  Also look for sections that specifically address Oracle as a source and as a target.

To minimize downtime during the migration choose "Migrate existing data and replicate ongoing changes" when creating the Replication Task.  This will allow ongoing access to your EC2 instance while the data is being migrated.

Since you are so dependent on LOBs you will want to make sure that you specify "Full LOB mode" for "Include LOB columns in replication".